# Python function for splitting strung together word into individual words

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to come up with a function that takes entries like

> "businessidentifier", "firstname", "streetaddress"

and outputs

> "business identifier", "first name", "street address"

This seems to be a fairly complicated problem involving NLP, since the function will have to iterate over a string and test against a vocabulary to see when it arrives at a word in the vocabulary, but for the first example "businessidentifier" might be seen first as "bus I ness identifier". Has anyone come across a function that accomplishes this task?

Comment: You might need to look into a language model... a naive approach might be to try all possible ways to break the sentence such that you end up with valid words, then use a language model to tell you which possible sentence is most likely. I doubt there's any simple function you can call which does this for you, though

Comment: I think this is a two step problem: 1) You're going to need to identify possible words which shouldn't be too hard given enough compute time and a corpus. 2) Given all the possible combos of words identify the "most" correct sentence given some NLP or other technique. Second step is definitely non-trivial and the first step will take exponentially long given large string(s) and a representative corpus.

Comment: this is what I figured. thank you both for confirming my suspicions, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to get a lot of English words, i used [nltk](https://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2014/11/03/get-a-list-of-all-english-words-in-python/) here. Then I loaded all words into dict so that all words that started for example with 'a' are in dict `eng_dict` under key 'a' to make searching for words faster. Then I sorted all words by their length so that when we look for words in our sentence we first are going to try to match it with longest ones so given 'businessidentifier' we'll first check 'business' instead of for example 'bus'.
Now that we have our words in nice format we can create function to match our sentence with that words. Here I created recurrent function that tries to match all words that starts with same letter as sentence and if we find one then add it to our return list and recurrently look for next one.

```
from nltk.corpus import words
word_list = words.words()

eng_dict = {chr(i): sorted([word for word in word_list if word[0] == chr(i)], key=len, reverse=True) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)}

def split_into_words(x):
    ret = []
    for word in eng_dict[x[0]]:
        if x.startswith(word):
            ret.append(word)
            x = x[len(word):]
            break
    if len(x) != 0:
        ret.extend(split_into_words(x))
    return ret

raw_sentences = ["businessidentifier", "firstname", "streetaddress"]
finall_sentence = [split_into_words(i) for i in raw_sentences]

print(finall_sentence)
```

Output:

```
[['business', 'identifier'], ['first', 'name'], ['street', 'address']]
```

Comment: this is great! basically what I was in the process of creating, but much more concise. Thanks so much for writing this!

Comment: Glad to have been for help!